# Knockout syntax error warning but it still works

Tags: knockout.js

Can anyone shed any light on this?  I'm getting a compiler warning in `VS2013/C#` on this line but yet it still works....

```
SendData = ko.toJSON({
    UserName: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.UN)),
    Notes: self.Notes,
    nRecID: @Html.Raw(Model.pkRecID),
    AddColors: self.AddColors
})
```

The warnings are on the commas between the elements.  All the compiler says is, `"Syntax error"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a side-effect of mixed client-side and server-side code.  Visual Studio knows that the `@Html.Raw(...)` is server-side code so it ignores it when parsing your client-side javascript.  So what Visual Studio sees is:

```
SendData = ko.toJSON({ UserName: , Notes: self.Notes, nRecID: , AddColors: self.AddColors })
```

As you can see, that isn't valid javascript since you're not providing a value for UserName or nRecID.  Anyway, you can safely ignore it.